# Gradle - delete published artifacts from local maven repository

Tags: gradle

I'm trying to work out how to get Gradle to delete published artifacts from the local maven repository. I figured it should be as easy as setting up a delete task, but this doesn't seem to work...

```
task cleanMavenLocal(type: Delete) {
    delete '~/.m2/repository/example'
}
```

If it's even possible from Gradle, any ideas how?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with Gradle's [Delete](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Delete.html) task since files passed to `delete` are interpreted relative to the current project directory (see [Documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project:files(java.lang.Object[]))).

However, Gradle build files are executable code. An ad-hoc task should do the trick.

```
task cleanMavenLocal {
    doLast {
        new File('~/.m2/repository/example').deleteDir()
    }
}
```